# MongoDb shell error. Not able to type commands into the shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongoose, mongo-shell

I have MongoDB installed on Windows 10. The server is running. The problem is, when I open the mongo shell, **I can't type any commands after this**:

```
MongoDb shell version: 3.2.6
Connecting to: test
```

See screenshot image:
[image]

What is the problem? I need to command the mongo shell to create a database but I can't do that since it doesn't pick up anything I type at the point.

Comment: Have you started the server (mongod) before connecting from mongo shell? It seems there's no connection to it. Antivirus/firewall could also block the connection to server.

Comment: Server was disconnected. That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: server (mongod) was disconnected. That was the problem.

Comment: how to make it connect ?